# Requests change language from ASP

Tags: python, python-requests, asp-classic

I am working on some scraps, and making tests, but i don't know how to change the web language if it's from an ASP file/web.

[This](https://www.microdetectors.com/prodotti/sensori-di-prossimit%C3%A0/C12P@00-3A/cap-m12-dc-plastico-no-nc) is the web

From Google Chrome Tools I saw when you click on a language, it calls an `.asp` file:

```
Common/Source/WG2/wg_ServerRequestFramework.asp
```

But I don't know how to give it params to to get the HTML on the language I want. Every time I try, I got an error or nothing.

My code is:

```
headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    }

product_link = url + '/prodotti/a/' + productname.replace('/', '@')+"/"

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(product_link, headers=headers)
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
    language_link='https://www.microdetectors.com/Common/Source/WG2/wg_ServerRequestFramework.asp'

params={'typeRequest': 'salvaSession','NomeSession': 'CodLingua', 'ValoreSession': 'SPA', 'CodVerifica': '8TWoHMM0', 'UtenteAtt':''}
r=s.post(language_link, headers=headers, data=params, cookies = {'CodVerificaAccesso': '8TWoHMM0', 'CodLingua':'ita'})
print(r.text)
```

I think i am doing everything wrong? Hope you can help me :(

Comment: you only want to change language ??..

Comment: I think is more easy if you make the requests directly to https://www.microdetectors.com/prodotti/sensori-di-prossimità/C12P@00-3A/cap-m12-dc-plastico-no-nc and in your variable CodLingua change the language

Comment: Im trying, adding params, data and headers to request POST, and can't get it work, at web or at ASP,  ASP gives me a blank response, and web just give me html in Italian

Comment: for me work , let me see

Comment: I am using the same code i posted here and i only get blank response, at the last print, just print nothing.